# Проблема с парсинг xml

Tags: jquery, xml, парсер, xmlparser

```
Выдает эту ошибку 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/26063.xml. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://site.ru' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.


$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://export.yandex.ru/weather-ng/forecasts/26063.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});




function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("forecast").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="book"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("station").text() + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("weather_type").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("weather_type").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".book").fadeIn(1000);

    });



}
```

Как правильно обращаться,с файлом локальным работает,с такой ситуации не работает.

Comment: Придется через сервер обращаться к тому сайту и возвращать с сервера в JS полученный XML. Ибо политика безопасности.. CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так это уже кросс-доменный запрос получается - вот есть статейка в учебнике Кантора по данной теме - https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain